# Struct and file handling

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

The program I am making must store the values in the text file on their respective variables. The problem seems to arise in the inner loop. I have the respective structs already defined. The program runs properly for the outer loop but when it proceeds in the inner loop, the file pointer does not read the proper values from the text file and outputs "0.0" and does not proceed with the processes from the outer loop altogether.

my input file looks something like this:

```
GENERAL
1   4

PANELS
1   2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1 1
2   2.2 3.2 4.2 5.2 6.2 7.2 2
    1   2.21    3.21    4.21    5.21
    2   2.22    3.22    4.22    5.22
3   2.3 3.3 4.3 5.3 6.3 7.3 0
4   2.4 3.4 4.4 5.4 6.4 7.4 4
    1   2.41    3.41    4.41    5.41
    2   2.42    3.42    4.42    5.42
    3   2.43    3.43    4.43    5.43
    4   2.44    3.44    4.44    5.44

MATERIAL
1   1000.0  2000.0  3000.0  4000.0
2   1010.0  2020.0  3030.0
3   1010.1  2020.2

CHB
1   10  20  30  2
2   11  22  33  1
```

these are just placeholders to see if they are stored. single digits are integers while floats have decimal points.

here is the code

```
typedef struct _open
{
    int id;
    double length;
    double height;
    double origX;
    double origY;
    int frames;

    double thickness;
    double E;
    double v;
}CHBOpening;

typedef struct _panels
{
    int id;
    double length;
    double height;
    double origX;
    double origY;
    double origZ;
    double angle;
    int nOpenings;
    int nReinforcement;
    double *xReinf;
    double sx;
    double xReinf0;

    CHBUnit *chb;
    CHBOpening *openings[];
}CHBPanel;

typedef struct _chb
{
    int nStories;
    int nModes;
    int nIter;
    int nPanels;
    CHBPanel *panels[];
}CHBStructure;
int ReadPanelBlock (FILE *fp, CHBStructure *S)
{
    int i,j;
    S->panels = malloc(S->nPanels*sizeof(CHBStructure));
    for (i=0; i< S->nPanels; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&S->panels[i].id);
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].length);
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].height);
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].angle);
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].origX);
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].origY);
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].origZ);
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&S->panels[i].nOpenings);
        if (S->panels[i].nOpenings > 0)
        {
            S->panels[i].openings = malloc(sizeof(CHBOpening)*S->panels[i].nOpenings);

            for (j=0; j<S->panels[i].nOpenings;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%d",&S->panels[i].openings[j].id);
                fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].openings[j].length);
                fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].openings[j].height);
                fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].openings[j].origX);
                fscanf(fp,"%lf",&S->panels[i].openings[j].origY);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try to step through the code, line by line, in a debugger, to see what it actually does.

Comment: By the way, are you sure about that first `PANELS` line, with id `1`? Wouldn't that last `1` (which gets written to `nOpenings`) on the line mean that the code expects one extra line to read? One extra line which doesn't exist, making the parser go out of sync.

Comment: As already commented in the previous post: cancel `[]` for `openings` and `panels` members of structs.

Comment: Lastly, does this really compile without any errors or even warnings? Take for example the `panels` member of the `CHBStructure` structure, you declare `panels` as a [flexible array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) of pointers, what you want here is really just a pointer, i.e. `CHBPanel *panels;`. Same thing with the `openings` pointer in the `CHBPanel` structure. There are also some other errors, which might cause the problems you have, and for which I will add an answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry for the typo, was testing the error catching for that line.

Comment: @LPs already did the correction. copied the wrong line. thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate `pannels` you do

```
S->panels = malloc(S->nPanels*sizeof(CHBStructure));
```

The problem here is that you use `sizeof(CHBStructure)` instead of `sizeof(CHBPanel)`. The problem with this is that `sizeof(CHBStructure) < sizeof(CHBPanel)`, so you don't allocate enough memory for the data you read.

That will lead to writing out of bounds, and *undefined behavior*.

<strike>This is in *addition* to the "typo" in the input file, which will lead you to enter the inner loop when there's nothing to read.</strike>

Comment: Thanks! This corrected the problem with the loops and UB.